# Ошибка при добавлении данных в таблицу (pgsql)

Tags: postgresql, insert

Пишу запрос на добавление данных из одной таблицы в другую.

```
INSERT INTO tb2
    SELECT t1.type::int AS type, t1.newUrl::character varying(30) AS domain, t1.countRow::int AS count FROM(
        SELECT Type, SUBSTRING(Url FROM '\//(.+?)\/') AS newUrl, COUNT(url) AS countRow 
        FROM tb1 
        GROUP BY newUrl, Type 
        ORDER BY Type ASC
    ) AS t1
```

Таблица tb2 содержит поля (id, type, domain, count)

Вываливается такая ошибка

```
ERROR:  column "type" is of type integer but expression is of type character varying
LINE 17:  SELECT t1.type::int AS type, t1.newUrl::character varying(3...
                                       ^
HINT:  You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
SQL state: 42804
Character: 414
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, в чем ошибка?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка - типичная для лентяя. В таблице назначения не указаны поля, в которые выполняется вставка. Запрос следует изменить на

```
INSERT INTO tb2 (type, domain, count) SELECT ...
```

> А зачем id добавлять? Он же автоинкремент

А сервер тупой. И делать он будет то, что ты сказал, а не то, что ты хотел. Не указаны поля? значит, вставлять будет все, ибо догадаться, какие поля не вставлять, он не может.

"Всё, что не указано явно, будет сделано как угодно..."

Comment: Тут не в лени дело а в том, что редко использую sql. А за ответ спасибо

Comment: @Yurrr *редко использую sql* Тем более!!! соблюдайте **ВСЕ**, даже самые минимальные и на первый взгляд лишние, требования к синтаксису. В запросах нет ничего лишнего. А всё, что не указано явно, всё равно будет дополнено сервером - вот только не факт, что правильно. Сервер - он реально тупой. Иначе бы сперва думал не "как сделать", а "как бы отвертеться"...

Answer (score 1):

так написано же в ошибке что поле type в tb2 -> integer, а в таблице tb1 у него text, Вы пропустили поле id в tb2 в Insert`е, Вы вставляете type из tb1 в поле id tb2. Несоответствие типов.

Comment: Нет, типы в таблице полностью совпадают. В вопросе поправил. А зачем id добавлять? Он же автоинкремент

Answer (score -1):

Он тебе даже подчеркнул что t1.newUrl поверь правильно ли ты его указал

Comment: вот точно также как во вложенной запросе